# matlab correlation matrix of a huge matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have an X matrix of dimensions 37,000,000 by 22, and I want to compute the correlation matrix of X.

I.e.,

```
X_corr = corr(X,'type','Spearman');
```

And I'd like the size of X_corr to be of 22 by 22.

But it takes forever, is there anyway to compute the correlation matrix faster for such long matrices?

Thanks!

Comment: @Bitwise sorry, 22 by 22, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Unless you have special structure in X you can exploit, I'm afraid it takes O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by @Bitwise's solution, I looked into the implementation of `corr`. (You can do so by simply typing `edit corr`. It has a loop over pairs of variables since it wants to deal with NaN's. If you don't have NaN's in your data, you can compute Spearman's correlation simply as:

```
X = rand(3e6, 22);
R = tiedrank(X); % Elapsed time is 8.956700 seconds.
C = corrcoef(X); % Elapsed time is 0.579448 seconds.
```

which should be same as

```
C2 = corr(X, 'type', 'Spearman'); Elapsed time is 9.501480 seconds.
```

But it's about the same speed.

Answer (score 2):

Try corrcoef():

```
>> X=rand(1000000,22);
>> tic;corr(X);toc
Elapsed time is 18.320141 seconds.
>> tic;corrcoef(X);toc
Elapsed time is 0.494406 seconds
```

Also this is almost what you want (I don't have enough memory for 37e6x22):

```
>> X=rand(10000000,22);
>> tic;corrcoef(X);toc
Elapsed time is 7.620509 seconds.
```

**Edit:**

If you want Spearman, you can convert to ranks and then calculate Pearson, which is equivalent. Sorting isn't that bad:

```
>> X=rand(10000000,22);
>> tic;sort(X);toc
Elapsed time is 31.639637 seconds.
```

Comment: `corrcoef` only computes Pearson's correlation, I think.

Comment: @Memming Spearman wasn't explicitly asked for in the text, just in the code. Also he can rank and then do Pearson, which is equivalent.

Comment: True. But in that case ranking would take most of the computation.

Comment: @Memming it would take most of the computation but could still be faster than corr() - see my edit.